# Pandas: increment datetime

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, dataframe, timedelta

I need to do some actions with `date` in df column

```
buys['date_min'] = (buys['date'] - MonthDelta(1))
buys['date_min'] = (buys['date'] + timedelta(days=5))
```

But it return

> TypeError: incompatible type [object] for a datetime/timedelta operation

How can I do it to column?

Comment: `type [object]` hints that there are at least some values that are not datetimes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you need first convert column `date` [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html), because `type` od values in column `date` is `string`:

```
buys['date_min'] = (pd.to_datetime(buys['date']) - MonthDelta(1))
buys['date_min'] = (pd.to_datetime(buys['date']) + timedelta(days=5))
```

EDIT:

You need parameter [`format`](http://strftime.org/) to [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) and then another solution is with [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html)

```
buys = pd.DataFrame({'date':['01.01.2016','20.02.2016']})
print (buys)
         date
0  01.01.2016
1  20.02.2016

buys['date']= pd.to_datetime(buys['date'],format='%d.%m.%Y') 
buys['date_min'] = buys['date'] + pd.to_timedelta(5,unit='d')
print (buys)
        date   date_min
0 2016-01-01 2016-01-06
1 2016-02-20 2016-02-25
```

Comment: it return error `TypeError: incompatible type [object] for a datetime/timedelta operation`. Data are like `01.01.2016, 20.02.2016`

Comment: I add solution, please check it.

Comment: `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'TimeDelta'`